# Populating a Dropdownlistfor with multiple ids

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I am using a dropdownlistfor html helper to pick ingredients in a dish. I can get it to display all the ingredients, i can make it post the value's, but i cant seem to populate it when i want to edit a dish with existing ingredients.

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        DishViewModel dvm = new DishViewModel();
        dvm.Dish = facade.GetDishGateway().Get(id);
        dvm.Dish.Ingredients.ForEach(x => dvm.SelectedIds.Add(x.Id));
        return View(dvm);
    }
```

My viewmodel:

```
public class DishViewModel
{
    Facade facade = new Facade();
    public DishViewModel()
    {
        SelectedList = facade.GetIngredientGateway().GetAll().FirstOrDefault().Id.ToString();
        SelectedIds = new List<int>();
    }
    public Dish Dish { get; set; }



    public List<int> SelectedIds { get; set; }
    public string SelectedList { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> SelectList
    {
        get
        {
            List<SelectListItem> temp = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (var item in facade.GetIngredientGateway().GetAll())
            {
                temp.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.Name + ": " + item.Price + ",-", Value = item.Id.ToString() });
            }
            return temp;
        }
    }
}
```

My View:

```
<div class="form-group row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dish.Ingredients, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedIds, Model.SelectList, new { @multiple = "multiple"})
        </div>
    </div>
```

By my understanding, the model => model.selectedIds is the one populating the dropdownlistfor, but it does not seem to work

Comment: You still need to populate your SelectList on your Edit action.

Comment: I populate the selectedids using the foreach loop, and the selectlist is populated in the get method.

Comment: Ah, the SelectList looks like it's populated in your View when you call Model.SelectList

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Html.DropDownListFor` renders a standard `select` element, where only one option may be marked as selected.

If you want a select multiple, then you should use `Html.ListBoxFor`.